# Using OpenCV's KNearest Neighbour - OpenCV; C++

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, knn

I'm want to use OpenCV's KNN algorithm to classify 4 features into one of two classes. In a text file, I have my training data in the following format:

> feature_1,feature_2,feature_3,feature_4,class

where feature_1, feature_3, feature_4 and class are integers and feature_2 is of type float. The first line of the text file contains the headings for each feature.

However, the OpenCV documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html) states that the train function requires the training data in the Mat data structure.

I'm confused as to how I can convert my text file of training data, to a Mat. If anyone can help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, OpenCV implements `CvMLData` which can read `csv` files (and    your file is a comma separated file).

according to documentation:    http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/mldata.html

Once you create an CvMLData object, you can use read_csv method:

```
read_csv(const char* filename)
```

to load it, and then use `get_values()` to get pointer to the input data as `Mat` and `get_responses()` to get the pointer to the labels as `Mat`

To set which column is considered as "response" (label) use the `set_response_idx` method